# Example of function of a single random variable.

Tags: probability

Take a look at this document: [*Functions of random variables*; Abdel-Hamid Soubra, Emilio Bastidas-Arteaga](http://hal.in2p3.fr/in2p3-01082914v2/document)

In the section **$2.2$**, they have given an example about application for an exact distribution of a **function of a single random variable** using Normal Distribution where,

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{\displaystyle - \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \left (\frac{x - 
 \mu}{\sigma}\right)  ^2 }$$

and,

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{\displaystyle  \left [\frac{ \frac{1}{2}( \sigma y + \mu -\mu)  ^2 }{\sigma^2}\right] } \left| \sigma \right| $$

<sup>**Note:** *to me, the above equation is apparently incorrect.*</sup>

Can anyone explain the same concept of function of random variables using a simpler equation? How about $y=mx+c$ ?

Comment: Your placement of $|\sigma|$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used in the book is precisely a linear one, written

$$y=\frac{x-\mu}\sigma$$ or $$x=\sigma y+\mu.$$

If you plug this in the initial distribution,

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{\displaystyle - \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \left (\frac{x - 
 \mu}{\sigma}\right)  ^2 }$$

the expression simplifies to

$$f_X(x)=f_X(\sigma y+\mu)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{\displaystyle - \frac{y^2}{2} }.$$

The purpose of this section is to explain why the $\sigma$ at the denominator needs to vanish to obtain the distribution $f_Y(y)$ from $f_X(x)$ (this is because the distribution must remain normalized.)

$$f_X(x)=\sigma f_Y(y)$$ (absolute value omitted.)